# How do I include properties file or config file in flex application (I am also using swiz framework)

Tags: apache-flex, properties, config, swiz

I have a flex application which contains different feature that includes google maps, twitter, facebook etc.

Currently I have hardcoded api keys in the code it self but I want to use a properties file/config file where I can put such things and use anywhere I want in the application.

Is it possible to achieve this in flex? 
I am using swiz framework. Is it possible to achieve this using this framework?

Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 1):

We use an external xml config file chock full of config settings for dev, staging, and production environments. Load it into your app at application complete and parse the xml nodes into a value object and store it in your model.

Jeff 
ReUrgency.com

Answer (score 1):

if you require LOCAL CONFIGURATION (the configuration specific for each client) then the easiest way to do in flex/air application is using sharedobject because filereference has been limited only for air application. [ticlib](http://code.google.com/p/ticlib/) has an easy and natural way to do local configuration, you only need to add `[Config]` annotation on your variable or getter then you event don't need to care about how to create and manage shared object. you can take a look at this [blog post](http://hemocoid.blogspot.com/2011/05/creating-keep-login-in-adobe-flexair.html) for real time use.

Answer (score 0):

The [Swiz Example Applications](https://github.com/swiz/swiz-examples) have many good examples of this. Look for anywhere they are loading a service config. I believe SwizDemoApp has an example of this, or it could be SwizPresentationModelExample (those were the two I looked at, and one of them had the method I use in my Swiz apps now). :)